# “Feel like” vs. “feel as though” vs. “feel that”

Tags: grammar

I hear a lot of people use “I feel like” + subject + verb, but I'm not sure whether it's grammatically correct. Someone once told me it was incorrect.

For example, if someone said, “I feel like I annoy people,” would it be considered grammatically correct or incorrect?

If it's incorrect, should “I feel as though” or “I feel that” be used?

Comment: (It's not an exact duplicate...)  'Like' is grammatical but informal.  It can be used as a conjunction (as in your example) or a preposition ("I feel like an annoying person").  But what is it in "I feel like annoying people"?

Comment: The post cited as already answering the question does not deal with "feel as though" at all.